# UITableView in a xib is not calling cellForRowAtIndex

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a XIB that has a bunch of views in it (iPad). One of the views is a UITableView. The delegate was set via IB. When you run the app `cellForRowAtIndex` is not being called. As a matter of fact, in this file, there is also no `numberOfRowsInSection` or `numberOfSections` methods. There is only a `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

So I wrote a `cellForRowAtIndex` and manually set `self.table.delegate = self`.

If I click a cell the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is executed.

I honestly am at a loss? How can this even happen?

Answer (score 5):

Add:

`self.table.dataSource = self;`

`cellForRowAtIndex`is a datasource protocol method, so you must set the datasource to self as well in order for the controller to respond to the datasource protocol.

---

Comment: I would personally make the connection in Interface Builder, but doing it programmatically works too.

Comment: It is set in IB along with the data delegate, but still not being called.

Comment: I have set the datasource again. The UITableViewDataSource is now in the .h file. And still the cellForRowAtIndexPath is NOT being called.

Comment: Have you tried to reload the table data? `[self.table reloadData];`

Answer (score 1):

If this controller is anything other than a UITableViewController, do not forget to add the following to your .h file:

```
@interface myViewController: UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is causing the problem, however an easy fix is that in your `-(void)viewDidLoad` method you could call `[self.table reloadData]` which forces it to manually call all of the functions

Somethign else that occurred to me is that you said "numberOfRowsInSection or numberOfSections is not implemented"... Those methods are required for a table view and oyu must make sure to implement them. That could very well be the problem

Answer (score 0):

In your .h you need to add the Datasource and Delegate declarations

```
@interface HDMainViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

and in you .m file where you create your tableview you need to set

```
tableview.delegate = self;
tableview.dataSource = self;
```

Now your dataSource and Delegate methods should work